# Advance filter to exclude numeric subfolders in Request URI

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics

I want to remove all numeric subfolders from Request URI's. Using a Search and Replace filter does half the job.

e.g: Request URI has the form `/abc/1234/abc/1234`

```
Search string => /[0-9]*/
Replace string => /
/////////////////////////
Desired outcome => /abc/abc/
Actual outcome => /abc/abc/1234/
```

https://regexr.com/3lg6h

Basically, Google Analytics does not return global results. How can I overcome this obstacle?

Comment: why don't you simply add a gloal flag with `/` as remplacement string?

Comment: @Flying_whale how do I do that in google analytics? Reworded - Is a global flag supported in google analytics?

Comment: Here is my attempt about the regex ONLY (since i don't know enough about Google Analytics) : https://regex101.com/r/htMjOF/1

Comment: @Falt4rm same issue, where global flag is not selected, the regex does not pick up both numeric subfolders.

Comment: Sorry, i don't see a way doing it without using global flag.